# Make Ubuntu accessible via ssh when IP is shared with several computers at home

Tags: networking, software-installation, ssh

I installed Ubuntu and would like it to be accessible with my other computers via SSH.

I tried, but for now it doesn't work. I found out that all the computers at home have the same IP address, so accessing ssh with the IP doesn't distinguish which computer I need to access.

I found some topics on the Internet, but they are outdated, refer to files that don't exist. What is the updated way to do it?

Comment: You need to forward port 22 on your home router to your Ubuntu PC

Comment: I believe you are mixing up local and public IP addresses (also, probably read up on [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)). If you need to access machines locally, just use the local IP address. If you need to access from the internet, you need to set up port forwarding for NAT to work.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that opening port 22 to the internet might not be a good idea, since it's the default attack surface for SSH. Changing to another port than 22 might reduce the attack surface somewhat.

Comment: Nice Artur, if you had access with ssh and now you don't; maybe you enabled firewall and it blocked port 22. if you enabled UFW, then try this: `sudo ufw allow 22`